# Identify this potted plant found at grocery store?

Tags: identification, houseplants, plant-health

I saw this potted plant at a local grocery store. It was USD $10 and there was only one.

Can someone identify this plant? Is it fast-growing? Does it have flowers? Is it indoor or outdoor?

Does it have any practical uses?

[image]

Comment: Oh good, I'm not the only person who impulse-buys potted plants with no idea what they need. :)

Comment: It's such a wonderful easy going indoor plant! I have variegated variety, but it "blooms" the same silly way. It is fast growing and propagating easily by simply placing cuttings (I do it when branches get too long to stay upright) into water for a week or so. And then you can start all over again. It does well in the sun and/or partial shade, but was doing really great on the sunny windowsill in the bathroom. I let it grow free there and it ended up with 5 feet long branches surrounding my bath. Now, I prefer to put 2-3 cuttings together in the same pot and just maintain the shape by cutting.

Answer (score 3):

It is [Peperomia obtusifolia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peperomia_obtusifolia). I don't know what "fast" means to you, but I can say that you can keep it in this pot for a year before it will need to be up-potted.

Yes, it has "flowers" - the green stalk that grows upright from the clump of leaves closest to the camera in your picture. It is an indoor plant if the temperature outside goes below 15 °C (59 °F).

On a sidenote, it needs more water than other succulents, but still less than other houseplants, so don't overwater. If you overwater, the leaves at the base of the plant will turn yellow, so it's easy to find out what's the maximum amount of water you can provide to have it grow faster without killing it.

Comment: Thank you. I live in the Caribbean so it will never go below 60 °F.

Comment: Can it be outside in a balcony? It would get shade most of the time, but it would receive sun a few hours a day due to the angle of the sun.

Comment: Yes, I kept mine in a closed balcony with SW orientation. It grew very well for two years until I moved and gifted it to a friend.